# Wildfly 8 Final Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, http-status-code-404, wildfly, spring-java-config

I am using Wildfly 8 Final, a WebApplicationInitializer implementation instead of a web.xml, Spring MVC 4 and Spring Security 3.2. The problem I have is that even though Wildfly says it has deployed the war successfully sometimes (not all the times) when I try to access any URI of the web app I get "404 Not Found". The problem remains until I redeploy the web app. Emptying the tmp folder does not matter-the error might still be there after restart.

I turned debug on and the only thing out of the ordinary is "Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling" (after a request). The thing is that I get this message in both situations.

Here is my WebApplicationInitializer

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
        throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherServlet = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    dispatcherServlet.register(WebConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class,
            DataConfig.class);

    servletContext
            .addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(dispatcherServlet));

    servletContext.setInitParameter("defaultHtmlEscape", "true");

    servletContext.addListener(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());    
    
     FilterRegistration.Dynamic fr = servletContext.addFilter("encodingFilter",  
              new CharacterEncodingFilter());
           fr.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
           fr.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
           fr.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");
    
    servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain",
            DelegatingFilterProxy.class).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null,
            false, "/*");

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(
            "dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherServlet));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");
}}
```

and here is the security config:

```
public class SecurityConfig {
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public static class SecurityConfigForRest extends
        WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    TokenAuthenticationProvider tokenAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(tokenAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean()
            throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    protected TokenAuthenticationFilter getTokenAuthFilter()
            throws Exception {
        TokenAuthenticationFilter tapf = new TokenAuthenticationFilter(
                authenticationManagerBean());
        return tapf;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/rest/set/**",
                        "/rest/get/**")
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(getTokenAuthFilter(),
                        AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)
                .csrf().disable();

    }
}

@Configuration
@Order(2)
public static class SecurityConfigForWebApp extends
        WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(
                passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/index", "/forgotPassword").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/sysadmin/*").hasAnyRole("SYS_ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/admin/*")
                .hasAnyRole("SYS_ADMIN", "ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/user/*")
                .hasAnyRole("SYS_ADMIN", "ADMIN", "USER")
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/index")
                .successHandler(new SecurityLoginSuccessHandler()).and()
                .sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1)
                .expiredUrl("/sessionExpired").and().and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(new SecurityAccessDeniedHandler())
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }
}}
```

It really does not make much sense how sometimes it works OK and others it does not.

## Edit

[Not found log](http://pastebin.com/uieCcsLB)/Spring Security On

[Normal response](http://pastebin.com/38sH9Tfb)/(Spring Security On)

[Normal response](http://pastebin.com/2XsAwhjL)/(Spring Secutiry Off)

Comment: Try removing Spring Security and seeing if it still happens. This will help reduce the problem. Also please attach your logs.

Comment: @Rob Winch I added the logs as requested but I cannot be sure Spring Security causes this issue. It is not that easy to reproduce. To be more precise today I did not have any problem deploying the war for more that 5 times consequently on Wildfly Final but last Friday it took more than an hour to get rid of the "Not Found" issue. "Null ModelAndView" seems to be irrelevant because it is related with static content that is not server via a handler.